# Codeigniter models are just utility classes?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter, model

In the MVC that I'm accustomed to, model classes (usually) represent tables and objects of these classes are rows/domain objects. I don't understand in CodeIgniter why model classes appear to just be singleton utility classes. It feels wrong writing

```
$data = array('text' => 'hello');
$this->commentModel->insert($data);
```

instead of

```
$comment = new Comment();
$comment->text = 'hello';
$comment->save();
```

Can someone explain why CodeIgniter does models this way and make me feel better about it? (Or tell me what I can do to fix it.)

Comment: I don't know why they design like that in the first place, but you can achieve what you want by using Datamapper ORM (http://datamapper.exitecms.org/), it's the most popular ORM specifically built for Codeigniter.

Comment: @bobo Hey, if you want to make an answer I'll accept it. The other answers were helpful but I ended up going with Datamapper. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Models in CodeIgniter are designed using singleton pattern you're right. While this seems confusing to many people who are used to working with a more PHP OOP approach, there are a few reasons.

> The first most simple is that you can
>   load a model just the once and have it
>   available in the super-global for use
>   throughout the system.

That's the only real plus here, the rest are apologetic explanations.

> CI was built in 2006 with PHP 4
>   support as a main priority.

This is only just starting to change now EllisLab has dropped PHP 4 support from CI 2.0, but for now, that's how the framework works.

You can of course load a model then use whatever PHP 5 syntax you like for your models.

> $this->load->model('comment');
>
> $comment = new Comment();
>   $comment->text = 'hello';
>   $comment->save();

Answer (score 3):

CodeIgniter doesn't include an ORM.

I would suggest to see at Doctrine that can be easily integrated with CI:
http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Using_Doctrine_with_Code_Igniter/

Answer (score 2):

You can check out my articles on how to use Doctrine (ORM) with Codeigniter.

Part 1 of 11:
http://www.phpandstuff.com/articles/codeigniter-doctrine-from-scratch-day-1-install-and-setup