# Codeigniter models: only return not load? Are models just namespaces?

Tags: codeigniter

I'm finding out about how CI scopes things a bit late. I've been creating models like this:

```
$this->load->model('user');
$this->user->load ($user_id);
```

Then I'd pass around the $this->user object to be able to access all the various things I needed from that object, update properties and such.

I downloaded a Phil Sturgeon CI app callend PyroCMS and I see that he mostly *returns* data from his object's methods, much like a straight-up procedural function.

So, are models really only supposed to be used at namespaces in CI?

I'm finding that using them the way I am, with a just-now-discovered scope issue, I'm over-writing my models.

Of course the solution is the name it when loading, but that means I have to track and be wary of what name each one of them is using, which is going to be a problem.

Is this how others use the CI models, mainly returning things from them instead of using them as full featured objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found Phil Sturgeon responded to this question: [Codeigniter models are just utility classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463062/codeigniter-models-are-just-utility-classes) with essentially what I need to know. I can still use the loaded model by using the php `$object = new Class` syntax. I will do this:

```
class Companies
{
    private $_users;

    public function __construct ()
    {
        $this->load->model ('users');
        $this->_users = new Users;
    }
}
```

With the `private` and the `new` I think I'm safe finally. Probably I should go ahead and do that outside of the model, and not in the constructor, then pass it in as a dependency. I had given up on DI.

I think I've talked myself off the ledge.

Answer (score 2):

After 2 years with CI, here's how I've begun to use the models:

```
// Singleton class to lookup Users and perform other
// tasks not related to one specific user
class User_model extends MY_Model {
    public static $CI;
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        self::$CI =& get_instance();
    }
    public function getByEmail($email)
    {
        $data = $this->db->where('email', $email)->get('users')->first_row();
        if ($data)
        {
            $user = new User;
            return $user->load($data);
        }
    }
    public function getAllUsers()
    {
        $data = $this->db->get('users')->result();
        foreach ($data as &$row)
        {
            $user = new User;
            $row = $user->load($row);
        }
        return $data;
    }
    //... other functions that makes sense in a singleton class
}

// Actual user object.  Instantiate one for every user you load...
class User {
    public function __construct($id)
    {
        $data = User_model::$CI->db->where('id', $id)->first_row();
        $this->load($data);
    }

     public function load($data)
     {
        foreach ($data as $k => $v)
        {
            $this->$k = $v;
        }
        return $this;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think the way I'm going to do it is how I outlined it when I answered my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114374/codeigniter-models-loaded-in-controller-overwritten-by-models-loaded-in-models/8121908#8121908. I think that will make it work the way that makes the most sense to me personally, and with little extra work. I've written a script to go through the codebase and find/replace all of the stuff to make it work.